# Save open files (session) in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I would like to save actually open files (tabs) and revert session (group of files) next time. Is there any options in NetBeans IDE 7.1.2? I know that NetBeans save automatically list of files that were opened when I quit the IDE. How to save opened files and switch between sessions?

Comment: any chance you accept the provided answer?

Answer (score 21):

You are looking for Project Groups. Take a look at the `File > Project Group` menu.

There you can create Project Groups that defines a list of opened projects. You can then switch from groups and the chosen projects will be opened/closed.

Netbeans saves the list of opened files per project so:

- if your groups do not share projects, you'll get the behaviour you want.
- if your groups share projects, the files opened in theses projects will follow you when switching between the groups.

<3 Netbeans

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, though I had to open all the files again after creating the group. Tnx!

Comment: In the "Create New Group" dialog, look at the status of the checkbox titled "Use Currently Open Projects". If you have it checked while projects and files are opened, entering the new group should not close the open files.

Answer (score 8):

Try Tab Groups.

In Netbeans (at least in version 7.3.1), click:
Window > Configure Window > New Document Tab Group

Now, open a new file and it should open in a separate window.

Then, you can toggle the Maximize Window / Restore Window buttons to switch between your windows / tab groups.

[image: Restore Window]
Restore Window Button

[image: Maximize Window Button]
Maximize Window Button

This is a convenient way to switch between sets of files, although you technically aren't saving these sets as you asked in your question.  It does remember these tab groups when you close and reopen Netbeans, though.

Comment: This is more useful for my purposes, Thanks user1411056

Comment: Window->Document Groups -- renamed in 8.1 to "Document Groups" and is surfaced to the "Window" menu, remembers on application close.